# Uninstall gmusic browser

Tags: xubuntu, uninstall, music-player

I would like to uninstall gmusic browser from my xubuntu installation. I find it does not meet my playback requirements. How do I go about this?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Hello, Mitch. It came with the xubuntu desktop which I run in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove gmusic browser.

Open terminal and run `sudo apt-get remove --purge gmusicbrowser`

Answer (score 5):

Just open a terminal and type this command:

```
 sudo apt-get autoremove gmusicbrowser
```

You can also use `--purge` option after `apt-get` to also remove the configuration files of gmusicbrowser.
This will remove package `gmusicbrowser`, it's dependencies and most probably `xubuntu-desktop` package. ***But, don't worry if you see `xubuntu-desktop` in the list of removable packages*** because that package is just a metapackage and removing it does not effect anything in your Xubuntu.

I have executed the command `apt-cache depends xubuntu-desktop  | grep gmusicbrowser` and it shows this line

```
Recommends: gmusicbrowser
```

saying, it is only a recommended package, which is not same as Dependency package.

These links may help your more to know about these facts:

- [Why removing gnome-core does not remove all of it's dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164941/why-removing-gnome-core-does-not-remove-all-of-its-dependencies/164952#164952)
- [This page about Package meta-information from debian handbook](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.package-meta-information.html)

Comment: @MarunduMuturi glad to help you. Can you consider accepting the answer? It may help future visitor. Thanks. You can accept it by clicking on the gray tick mark beside the answer

Comment: Removing the `xubuntu-desktop` package isn't that harmless: if it is missing, upgrades to future versions of the distribution may be problematic due to new packages brought in by the meta package not being installed.