# How to completely uninstall LXDE (12.04)?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, desktop-environments, lxde

I'm trying to remove LXDE from my 12.04 system. 
I've tried running the following commands (as root from a terminal): 

`apt-get remove lxde 

apt-get purge lxde 

apt-get autoremove` 



I've also tried [a rather lengthy command](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntu) that was linked to from [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86602/completely-remove-desktop-environment). 
However, when I log in, LXDE is still presented as an environment choice, and it still functions perfectly well, as if I've done nothing. 
I ran the above commands again, but got the following message:

`package . . . is not installed, so not removed.` 



So, where do I go from here, short of re-installing Ubuntu and all my programs?

Comment: LXDE is a metapackage and you need to know the name of packages installed during first installation to remove them. take a look to [this similar question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/164941/why-removing-gnome-core-does-not-remove-all-of-its-dependencies/164952#164952)

Comment: Can you post the output of the "lengthy command", perhaps something didn't work there. Have you installed lxde or lubuntu-desktop?

Comment: @Anwar I removed `lxde-core` and tried removing all the dependencies given by the original install (used `apt-get install -s lxde` to get list). still though, when I log in, LXDE still shows up (AND FUNCTIONS) as an environment choice in the menu.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you got this solved by now or not, but I think your problem is lxde-core is itself a meta package. To reverse

```
apt-get install lxde
```

you need to

```
apt-get remove lxde gpicview leafpad lxappearance lxde-core lxde-common lxinput lxmusic lxpanel lxsession lxsession-edit lxshortcut lxterminal openbox-themes openbox pcmanfm xarchiver xscreensaver
apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is, to first, check the dependency of the `lxde`.
You can do this using the `apt-cache` command.

```
sudo apt-cache show lxde
```

This enables you to remove dependency packages.
So far, this has worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge lxde*
```