# Uninstalling Plasma desktop

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, plasma-5

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS and installed plasma desktop using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop
```

But later I uninstalled it using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge plasma-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

After restarting my system, the login screen still gives me an option to choose Ubuntu(default) or Plasma. I want to remove plasma completely.

Answer (score 7):

Uninstalling packages that are installed as dependencies of a `metapackage` is often harder. Because, autoremove doesn't remove the packages pulled by a metapackage - See this question for an explanation of why [Why removing gnome-core does not remove all of it's dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164941/why-removing-gnome-core-does-not-remove-all-of-its-dependencies)

However, removing this curated list of packages will get rid of plasma desktop mostly, if not completely.

```
sudo apt --purge autoremove plasma-desktop-data plasma-workspace kded5 libkf5plasma5 libkf5runner5 kactivities
```

It should not remove other KDE5 applications (as far I can check), but it does remove, you need to install that package later manually.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also like to add on Anwar's answer by saying, also run `sudo apt purge kwalletmanager`.

It's a program that showed up after I installed KDE Plasma, if you do not need it you can uninstall it.