# installing kubuntu grub loader completely ubuntu 16.04

Tags: grub2, 16.04, kubuntu

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and installed plasma kde environment.
later found it had some bugs and tried to uninstall  it. `apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop` works but my grub loader is not changing back to previous version. And it still shows switching option in the login screen for plasma.

I need help. to roll back to original Ubuntu build. I have over 20GB of opt content and have only one partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To go back to previous grub background

If you want to go back to the Ubuntu's login screen and grub background, use this command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config text.plymouth
```

This will show you options to select something like below -

```
There are 5 choices for the alternative text.plymouth (providing /usr/share/plymouth/themes/text.plymouth).

  Selection    Path                                                                   Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/xubuntu-text/xubuntu-text.plymouth           150       auto mode
  1            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/kubuntu-text/kubuntu-text.plymouth           60        manual mode
  2            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/text/text.plymouth                           40        manual mode
  3            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-mate-text/ubuntu-mate-text.plymouth   100       manual mode
  4            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth             50        manual mode
  5            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/xubuntu-text/xubuntu-text.plymouth           150       manual mode
```

Select the one with Ubuntu by typing the number and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

### To remove most of the KDE and plasma components

Use the solution I gave in this question https://askubuntu.com/a/814627/61218