# Problem with Dark theme on GNOME, after uninstall Plasma KDE on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, kde, themes, uninstall

I've installed Plasma KDE on Ubuntu 20.04 and after i uninstall it with this command (which i found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814621/uninstalling-plasma-desktop)):

```
sudo apt --purge autoremove plasma-desktop-data plasma-workspace kded5 libkf5plasma5 libkf5runner5 kactivities
```

These weird white box started appear on some applications like Software, dconf Editor, System Monitor,...

This happened with every dark theme like yaru-dark, flat-remix,...

Is there anyway i can fix it ?
Thanks !

[Picture of weird white box on dconf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6lpb.png)

[Picture of weird white box on Software App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHKjQ.png)

[Picture of weird white box on System Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkWXD.png)