# How to debug slow keyboard sound and brightness Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: unity, sound, brightness

I got a really nice new laptop (no bragging here). Checked all was working and installed Unity. I have some issues and I would like to know how can I debug them:

- On restart, brightness levels are not the ones I last had, bluetooth is on for a while and then back off (should be always off). It might have to do with CPU level management
- If I change colume or brightness levels (from indicator or from keyboard) first change is instant, next change takes a while to update

The computer came with Plasma and Gnome installed and I'm pretty sure with Unity in the mix, I created a fighting for hardware control but I don't know how to debug those.

Anyone could lead me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed uninstalling Plasma Desktop (seems it conflitcs with Unity's Notification bubbles)

[Uninstalling Plasma desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814621/uninstalling-plasma-desktop)